# Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Redirector could not be converted to int laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to redirect user after some actions to route with parameters , I write something like this

```
  return redirect()-route('purchaseList' , ['shop' => $shopName , 'id' => $productId]);
```

but when it redirected it gives me this error :

Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Redirector could not be converted to int

btw $shopName and $productID are exist and problem is not this

this is my route

```
Route::get('/{shop}/purchase-list/{id}', 'ShopController@purchaseList')->name('purchaseList');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update the redirect method.

```
return redirect()->route('purchaseList' , ['shop' => $shopName , 'id' => $productId]);
```

You have to miss `>`.

Comment: @hassankhosro If your issue solved. Please accept and upvote the answer. Happy to help you!!